# How to read category name on PowerPoint chart?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

How to access the name of each category from chart in PowerPoint? This is what I did to get the name for series, so is there something similar for categories:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SeriesCollection seriesCollection = presentation.Slides[1].Shapes[2].Chart.SeriesCollection();
Series series2 = seriesCollection.Item(2);
var series_name = series2.Name;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(series_name));
```